# Changing ticks mark period in Holoviews heatmap

Tags: python, heatmap, bokeh, holoviews

I have the following heatmap made by Holoviews. I need to change x ticks to change the period of x ticks. [0,2,4,...] instead of [0,1,2,3,4,..]

```
data = [(i, j,  i*j) for i in range(10) for j in range(10)]
hv.HeatMap(data)
```

[Change from this graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSA2y.png)

[To this graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rG4mN.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With **HoloViews >= 1.13**, you can now use keyword `.opts(xticks)` and `.opts(yticks)` for setting continuous (non-categorical) ranges.

**Example:**

```
data = [(i, j,  i*j) for i in range(10) for j in range(10)]

hv.HeatMap(data).opts(xticks=[0, 3, 6, 9], yticks=[0, 5, 9])
```

**Resulting plot:**

[image: customizable heatmap xticks for continuous ranges]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that bokeh doesn't provide such function. However you can change the `doFormat` function of 
`xaxis.formatter` before draw the plot.

After run the following cell:

```
from bokeh.models import CustomJS
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension("bokeh")

def change_formatter(p, o):
    fig = p.handles["plot"]

    def callback(fig=fig):
        def do_format(t, e):
            return [label if i % 2 == 0 else "" for i, label in enumerate(t)]

        fig.renderers[0].formatter.doFormat = do_format    
    fig.js_on_change("inner_width", CustomJS.from_py_func(callback))

%opts HeatMap [finalize_hooks=[change_formatter]]
```

plot the `HeatMap`:

```
data = [(i, j,  i*j) for i in range(10) for j in range(10)]
hv.HeatMap(data)
```

here is the output:

[image]