# Plot Holoviews.Image using Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, plotly, bokeh, holoviews

I'm trying to make a 2D color plot of my low temperature transport measurement. The data were taken and saved in a series of .dat files. The data looks something like this:

```
B (T), T(K) , V (V), I (A)
0,     4.01, -10.0, 0.001
0,     4.02, -9.9, 0.001
...
```

Each file was taken at a specific magnetic field. (0 to 2 Telsa with 0.2T step) in total 11 files. I imported all the files and concatenate them into a single pandas `dataframe` which looks like this:

```
B, T, V, I
0,4.01,-10.0,0.001
0,4.02,-9.9,0.001
...
0.2,4.01,-10.0,0.001
0.2,4.02,-9.9,0.001
...
0.4,4.01,-10.0,0.001
0.4,4.02,-9.9,0.001
...
```

Now I want to make a 2D color plot with V and B as the x and y axis and I as z (color). How do I do that with `Holoview.Image`?

I know it can be done using using a **seaborn heatmap** but I want to use **holoview** for interactive plot and other functionalities. It also works with `Holoviews.HeatMap`, but `HeatMap` has a few problems. HeatMap axes are categorical not numerical, which makes it difficult and non-intuitive to set xticks, xlim, etc. (for example: [Changing ticks mark period in Holoviews heatmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49211006/changing-ticks-mark-period-in-holoviews-heatmap))

`Holoviews.Image` is more suitable for my data, but it accepts only gridded data, not columnar data like pandas dataframe.

I guess, in a nutshell, my question is how to convert `pandas dataframe` to gridded data in order to plot in `Holoviews.Image` element.

Answer (score 1):

ahuang11 answered on GitHub: https://github.com/pyviz/holoviews/issues/3686#issuecomment-488932024

```
import pandas as pd
import holoviews as hv
import hvplot.xarray

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'B': [0, 1, 2],
    'T': [2, 3, 4],
    'I': [5, 6, 7]
}).set_index(['B', 'T'])
df.to_xarray().hvplot.image('B', 'T', cmap='RdBu_r')
```

(I wanted to plot V as x axis not T, but it doesn't matter)

1. Set the columns intended for x and y axis to the index using df.set_index().
2. Use df.to_xarray() to convert pandas dataframe to xarray.
3. Use the xarray to plot or to create holoviews dataset:

```
ds = hv.Dataset(df_xarray,['B', 'V'] , 'I')
ds.to(hv.Image, ['B', 'V'], 'I')
```